# How to protect trouser/clothes from semen?

Tags: clothing, sex

I have Nocturnal emission (aka wet dream) almost every night, and as result when I wake up in morning I see that my trousers are wet with spots/stains of semen.

How can I protect my clothes from catching semen? Because it is very difficult for me to wash my trousers daily.

Answer (score 6):

The most effective way to prevent night time emission of semen from wet dreams...

Assuming you don't have a partner:

Day dreams with manual expression of the fluids.

If you have a partner:

Ask your partner for assistance.

This is a secular answer, some religious groups may not condone this advice. If in doubt discuss with your religious leader.  There are multitude of non-secular solutions to this issue.

Comment: Would have been my suggestion hadn’t the asker posted a second (closed) question in the same context stating that this was not an option that they (or he) wanted to consider. Anyway — +1

Comment: And your answer would have been the answer to said question (apart from the aforementioned disagreement on the asker’s side).

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is about the trousers themselves getting the semen, it probably means lack of underwear. Assuming this is true and you sleep without underwear, my tip is to wear underwear beneath the trousers while sleeping.

This way the semen will be absorbed inside the underwear and won't reach the trousers. In case of large volume that goes through, just put another pair of underwear on top.

While you will still have to clean up every day, cleaning up underwear should be much easier than trousers.

After giving it some more thought, I decided to go the extra mile and add tips regarding the underwear themselves. There are basically two main options:

1. Underwear that are meant to absorb liquids while being washable (also known as  Incontinence Briefs), it will make sure no semen will leak at all no matter how much you'll have. Downside is that you'll still have to wash them daily. From quick look around, [this brand](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VWSBAAS) appears to be good, it's not cheap but you buy three pairs at once, one time, and can keep using them for as long as you want.
2. Disposable briefs: you wear each pair once and just throw it away instead of washing it. It's originally meant for people in hospital/sauna/etc where you can't wash the underwear, but can't see reason why not using them on regular basis if you can afford it. Quick looking around gave [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09SYNLGTP), for example, appears to be reasonable price. If washing the clothes is a big concern, this can be the ideal solution. (Keep in mind that those aren't meant to absorb liquids though, so like I said before, in case of large volume of semen that gets through, wear two pairs at once.)

Comment: You use so many fancy words here... You practically talk about diapers for adults, right? Or? :)

Comment: @virolino well, it's not Quora or Reddit, so yeah I try to use the correct terms, no worry I had to Google most myself. #2 is one stage "before" diapers, it's what hospitals give the patients when they don't have their own underwear, I see the link is dead by now, will try to find alternative. Of course adult diapers are also an option, but see no reason to recommend when there are other options. ;)

Comment: It's OK, I just wanted to be sure we are on the same page. In my answer I suggested the "true" hack, instead of diapers :D The same basic idea.

Comment: @virolino cheers, and I fixed the link. Thanks for the heads up! :-)

Comment: That was not a real heads up, but... you are welcome! :)

Answer (score 5):

Do not sleep in your trousers, move them so far from your bed that they can not get dirty.

But do wear some clothing around the problem spot, like fitted underwear. And take it as given that will get dirty. If you use the underwear from the last day for the night and use cleans for the next day it should not be extra laundry either.

Comment: While the answer seems obvious, the last part contains a very good advise, as usually (?) people would wear clean underwear when going to sleep. I was expecting more upvotes here. :/

Answer (score 1):

Buy n pajama pants/shorts/preferred type of sleepwear, with n >= number of days between when laundry fits in your schedule. For example, if you do laundry each weekend, make sure you have at least seven pairs, better more.

Pick a fresh pair whenever needed.

Don’t put the wet pants in the laundry hamper, let them at least dry, or better give them also a quick rinse, to prevent mold, stains and bad smells.

Answer (score 1):

What if you make a habit of doing that yourself right before bed? Or maybe listen to a old or new voicemail from either one of your parents (any blood family or anyone who you consider being family). Maybe hearing that on repeat while your sleeping would change your thoughts and/or your release.
I'm a female, not sure how that happens when someone is sleeping. Those are only a idea, if they don't make sense for that specific issue please don't leave mean comments.

Comment: The first "hack" was already suggested in [this older answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/23745/1399), though not very clearly. The second hack is one of the more original ideas I've seen for long time, kudos for that! It's the opposite of common (?) practice that involves listening to things that arouse you while you sleep in order to achieve "wet dream" on purpose. As this appears to work, based on feedback from people who tried it, your idea might work as well.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the "doing that yourself right before bed", I'm pretty sure OP (and anyone who have same problem) thought about this as it's the trivial thing to do, and since he's not doing it, there must be a reason, e.g. religious reasoning or even medical: people with heart problems are sometimes advised by the doctors to not put lots of pressure on their system.

Comment: @JessicaFisher: on this site (actually, on all SE sites), we do not provide just random thoughts. We try to give real advice, with at least a minimum of confidence. Ideally, with scientific information (with links). Or we share similar experiences. Or at least we explain why some idea might be good. "Only an idea" is usually not enough to be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Shadow Wizard Chasing Stars](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/24752) mentions incontinence briefs (there are also pads). These are a bit expensive and bulky, designed to hold much more fluid. For this purpose, a thin disposable "panty liner" will perform the same function. You will find them in the "women's" section of the pharmacy. They are a thin, very absorbent pad with a waterproof backing and adhesive to keep it positioned in your underwear. The thinnest ones are designed to hold at least that much fluid. This will protect both your trousers and underwear.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your trousers getting dirty might be the smallest problem. When an old man starts having sexual desires again, he is immediately sent to have a prostate exam - and for good reasons.

So the first thing that I would do - I would undergo some medical tests to see if there is a problem of the body. Emissions EVERY night is not so common, afaik.

Additionally, especially considering the sexual characteristic of the problem: I would find a counselor (trainer, psychologist, call them any way you want), to find the cause of all those dreams and of all those emissions. You might be in for some interesting surprises there :)

---

Other than that, other users already answered the basic issue: wear underwear, wash often. Maybe even wear 2-3 layers of underwear during the night.

Ultimately, wear a plastic bag over the underwear, to restrict the spread of the emissions. You can make that from a 30L garbage bag, in which you make 2 additional holes, for your legs.If you are careful to wash and dry it, you can use it several times and be friendly with the environment.

The extreme idea is to wear a condom during the night, but that will most likely lead to other complications.

Comment: Well, a condom will just slip off, so don't think it's realistic option.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices and I have used both.

1. A thin plastic food storage bag and a rubber band. Use the cheap ones that require a twist tie for normal closure but don't use the tie in this application. Put your penis and balls in the bag and use the rubber band to hold them in the bag. Not too tight, but tight enough that your balls help hold everything in place. If you have a wet dream all will be in the bag. Wash the bag in the shower in the morning. Throw it away if it gets broken or otherwise yucky. I find a typical grocery store box of 50 lasts me at least 3 months.
2. My choice - Wear adult plastic underwear or adult plastic panties. Make certain they are the ones with leg elastic. Wash them in the shower. Any sticky will be confined.

Comment: The first option sounds like valid hack, might just work for OP. However note the second option you suggested was already mentioned in my own answer and expanded in Dolly's answer.